# BufferedReader readLine() issue: detecting end of file and empty return lines

Tags: java

I want my program to do something when it finds the end of a file (EOF) at the end of the last line of text, and something else when the EOF is at the empty line AFTER that last line of text. Unfortunately, BufferedReader seems to consider both cases equal.

For example, this is my code to read the lines to the end of the file:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Found an empty line at end of file.");
    }
}
```

If file.txt contained this, it wouldn't print:

```
line of text 1
another line 2//cursor
```

This wouldn't print either:

```
line of text 1
another line 2
//cursor
```

However, this will:

```
line of text 1
another line 2

//cursor
```

What reader can I use to differentiate the first two cases?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `BufferedReader.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` method. When end of file is reached, return value `-1`, you can check if the last buffer read ended with a line separator.

Admittedly, the code would be more complicated as it will have to manage the construction of lines from the read `char[]` buffers.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use `read` rather than `readLine` and handle end-of-line detection yourself. `readLine` considers `\n`, `\r`, and EOF all to be line terminators, and doesn't include the terminator in what it returns, so you can't differentiate on the basis of the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(String inputFilename) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename));

  ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
  String currentLine = "";

  int currentCharacter = br.read();
  int lastCharacter = -1;

  // Loop through each character read.
  while (currentCharacter != -1) {
    // Skip carriage returns.
    if (currentCharacter != '\r') {
      // Add the currentLine at each line feed and then reset currentLine.
      if (currentCharacter == '\n') {
        lines.add(currentLine);
        currentLine = "";
      } else {
        // Add each non-line-separating character to the currentLine.
        currentLine += (char) currentCharacter;
      }
    }

    // Keep track of the last read character and continue reading the next
    // character.
    lastCharacter = currentCharacter;
    currentCharacter = br.read();
  }

  br.close();

  // If the currentLine is not empty, add it to the end of the ArrayList.
  if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) {
    lines.add(currentLine);
  }

  // If the last read character was a line feed, add another String to the end
  // of the ArrayList.
  if (lastCharacter == '\n') {
    lines.add("");
  }

  return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reading from a BufferedReader that received its input from a socket input stream.
Everything worked fine until the last line, where the `readLine()` would just simply hang because the browser wouldn't send a newline terminator on post data.

This is my solution, to be able to read until the end of the input stream.

```java
public String getLine(BufferedReader in) 
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {       
        while(in.ready()) { 
            char input = (char)in.read();
            /**
              * This method only matches on " \r\n" as a new line indicator.
              * change as needed for your own line terminators
              */
            if(input == '\r') {
                /** If we can read more, read one more character
                  * If that's a newline, we break and return.
                  * if not, we add the carriage return and let the 
                  *    normal program flow handle the read character
                  */
                if(in.ready()) {
                    input = (char)in.read();
                    if(input == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        builder.append('\r');
                    }
                }
            }
            builder.append(input);
        }       
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @hmjd's solution or any other readers that can read byte by byte.

If you want to stick with reading line by line, you can use this.

```
    boolean EOF = (currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null;
    while(!EOF){
        // do things that will happen no matter it is EOF or not
        EOF = (currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null;
        if(!EOF){
            // do things that will happen no matter it is not EOF
        }else{
            // do things that will happen no matter it is EOF
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use

```
if (line.length()==0) {
    System.out.println("Found an empty line.");
}
```

Note: this will detect a blank line anywhere in the file, not just at EOF.

Comment: Actually, no. If the line was empty and contained nothing, it would still return a null.