# Read last line from a file

Tags: java, file-io

So I am trying to read a file in Java. It works fine, unless the last line is empty, in which case it gets ignored; but I need to read this empty line too.

Here is my code:

```
try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader("filename.txt"));

        String Line;

        while((Line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("L| " + Line);
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: this code shouldn't ignore any existing line, whether empty or not. Are you sure there is a line? Can you verify with `wc -l` and compare that to a counter you implement in your loop?

Comment: please close the stream `in` when done.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922859/bufferedreader-readline-issue-detecting-end-of-file-and-empty-return-lines

Answer (score 1):

first use scanner class...as they are hum easier to use....and then store each line in a list and then get the last line..here is the code:

```
public void readLast()throws IOException{
        FileReader file=new FileReader("E:\\Testing.txt");  //address of the file 
        List<String> Lines=new ArrayList<>();  //to store all lines
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){  //checking for the presence of next Line
            Lines.add(sc.nextLine());  //reading and storing all lines
        }
        sc.close();  //close the scanner
        System.out.print(Lines.get(Lines.size()-1)); //displaying last one..
    }
```