# BufferedReader appears to be missing trailing newline?

Tags: java, io

I have a string like: `b\na\n a \n a\n\ta\n` there should be 6 lines but the following code skips the last empty line.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.err.println("b4 line: " + line);
}
```

Using a scanner appears to work, but whats wrong with the bufferedReader?

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.err.println("b4 line: " + line);
}
```

Comment: All 3 answers below are absolutely **WRONG**. It does matter, because BufferedReader is treating both cases equivalently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922859/bufferedreader-readline-issue-detecting-end-of-file-and-empty-return-lines

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 lines as you have 5 times `\n` and nothing after the last `\n`.

So nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I count five lines. Your String ends with a \n so that would be the last line. There is no data after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` looks for `<line_content>\n` and returns `<line_content>` back. If you count this appearance in your example, you will realize, that it should only return five lines.

Comment: If I need to consider that a line, is it possible to do it?

Comment: Can you list the lines you expect to be found?

Comment: " b", "a", " a ", " a", "\ta", ""

Comment: You need to add one more \n to the file.